# How to change SystemAccentColor at runtime (UWP)?

Tags: c#, uwp

The app has a `GridView` in which each item is a color that the user can choose to customize the UI overriding the default `SystemAccentColor` (the one is defined by user on their system). 
I managed to get the color of the item but even though I assign it as new value for SystemAccentColor I am not able to update the UI.

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
        // FIRST APROACH -----

        GridViewItem gridViewItem = GVColors.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;

        Ellipse ellipseItem = gridViewItem.FindDescendant<Ellipse>();

        var theColor = (SolidColorBrush)ellipseItem.Fill;

        Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"] = theColor;


        // SECOND APPROACH ----

        Windows.UI.Color theColor2 = new Windows.UI.Color
        {
            A = 1,
            R = 176,
            G = 37,
            B = 37
        };

        var root = (FrameworkElement)Window.Current.Content;
        root.Resources["SystemAccentColor"] = theColor2;
}
```

I'm currently reading this blog entry [XAML Brewer, by Diederik Krols: Using a Dynamic System Accent Color in UWP](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2017/02/22/using-a-dynamic-system-accent-color-in-uwp/) but I want to know if the community knows another approach to change the accent color at runtime (or a method that I'm not aware of to Update/refresh the UI).

Comment: Does the second answer work? Can it solve your issue?

Comment: Yes but not really. The two answers were useful, I made a mix between them.
Your answer was very helpful in binding the values ​​and the `ColorPaletteResources` did the rest. The thing is, the app UI needed to be "refreshed" for the changes to take effect. What I did, a stinky hack, is implement a forced change of theme when choosing the color (If the theme was light: I forced a change to dark theme and again to a light theme in order to "refresh" the UI).

Answer (score 3):

> > I assign it as new value for SystemAccentColor I am not able to update the UI.

Since you statically bind SystemAccentColor and it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, event though the value of SystemAccentColor changes, the UI which bound with it won't update directly.

Based on your requirement, you can add a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface and add the SystemAccentColor as property in it. Then init the class instance in `Application.Resources`. After that, bind the UI with the SystemAccentColor property. For example, I create a class named SystemAccentColorSetting.

**SystemAccentColorSetting.cs:**

```
public class SystemAccentColorSetting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SolidColorBrush systemAccentColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    public SolidColorBrush SystemAccentColor
    {
        get { 
            return systemAccentColor; 
        }
        set { 
            systemAccentColor = value; OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:SystemAccentColorSetting x:Key="SystemAccentColorSetting"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Usage:**

Assume that we bind the Background of Button with the SystemAccentColor property.

**.xaml:**

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Background="{Binding SystemAccentColor, Source={StaticResource SystemAccentColorSetting}}">hello</Button>
```

**.cs:**

If you want to change the value of Background, just change the SystemAccentColor property.

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewItem gridViewItem = GVColors.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
    Ellipse ellipseItem = gridViewItem.FindDescendant<Ellipse>();
    var theColor = (SolidColorBrush)ellipseItem.Fill;

    ((SystemAccentColorSetting)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColorSetting"]).SystemAccentColor = theColor;
}
```

Comment: Although is a great approach to personalize some controls, doesn't solve my question. I want to override the `StaticResource SystemAccentColor` (the one that is user defined on their system) in order to update the app with in-app-user-selected color.  I've implemented your code to try to override `SystemAccentColor` in ThemeResources (App.xaml file) but is not working either. It seems that override it at run time turn it to transparent.

Answer (score 2):

**Starting from Win 10 1809** (build 17763), **you can use the `ColorPaletteResources`** Class.
By using it, you can change not only the Accent color at runtime, but also all the other system default colors for UI controls.

Due to a bug, you forst have to declare that `ColorPaletteResources` object into your App's XAML resources (with a key) and then you can use it at runtime.

Another bug is that, from what I have experimented some time ago, you can only change the Accent color for now, so you are lucky.

To see it in action, you can download ***Fluent XAML Theme Editor*** from the [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N2XD3Q8X57C) or from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/fluent-xaml-theme-editor).

Here is the link to the class [itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.colorpaletteresources) and to some [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/uwp/design/style/color#scoping-system-colors) on how to use it.

Comment: I totally forgot the `ColorPaletteResources`. Thank you. It is a great contribution to change some theme colors. Still, I am not able to implement it well (possibly it is my lack of general knowledge in C # and UWP). I've commented about what I did to resolve the issue in the comment section  if it is of your interest. :)